# Invalid Application ID: The provided Application ID is invalid on page with fbml

Tags: facebook

I've searched extensively but haven't found any good answers for this issue.  We've got fbml working on our site but in some situations (like http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/anthrax-files/) I also get a message saying **Invalid Application ID: The provided Application ID is invalid** - on occasion it even comes up twice.

I've run the pages through face book's lint already and made some changes.  But I'm stumped - in particular because it doesn't always appear, only sometimes.  Anyone have any insights as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: in safari and chrome it shows in black text on the left side of the screen - over some of the existing content.  and it's vertically aligned with the Facebook like button and recommendations box on the right rail

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for the answer to this:  a variable I failed to disclose in this question is that we use Disqus on the pages in question.  The Facebook Application ID that previously worked in Disqus stopped working suddenly.  Swapping in a new Application ID authorized to the domain solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I got this error when using a "Like this on Facebook" widget with the wrong Facebook App ID. Unknown to me there was a different App ID in an og meta tag in the header and the two seemed to conflict with each other.